# C++ function that allows arbitrary class input

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading

Right now I have a class A which has a method f:

```
class A{
public:
    double f(double x){return 0.0;};
};
```

and I have another class B with another method f:

```
class B{
public:
    double f(double x){return 0.0;};
};
```

I would like my function myfun to take in either class A or class B without having to overload the function:

```
double myfun(A a){
    return a.f(1.0);
}
double myfun(B b){
    return b.f(1.0);
}
```

I don't want to overload the function because I will have three or more different classes with the method f(). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Inheritance is another way you could go.

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple template function:

```
template<typename T>
double myfun(T t) {
    return t.f(1.0);
}
```

And then you call it like:

```
A a;
myfun(a);

B b;
myfun(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [function templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

```
template <typename T>
double myfun(T t){
    return t.f(1.0);
}

int main()
{
  A a1 ;
  B b1 ;

  myfun( a1 ) ;
  myfun( b1 ) ;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/027d85bc28e72d51).

Answer (score -1):

Templates approach is indeed the way to go as mentioned already.
If you don't feel comfortable with templates, you can get the same effect by inheritance.

Use a base class that has myFun virtual (or pure virtual), then derive every subsequent class from that class.

```
class Base {
public:
virtual double f(double x)=0;
}

class A : Base {
public :
double f (double x){return 0.0};
}

class B : Base {
public :
double f (double x}{return 1.0};
}

double myFun(Base b) {
   return b.f(1.0);
}
```

This is an alternative.

Comment: Should be `double myFun(Base& b)` or `double myFun(Base* b)`

Comment: Thanks for the updated Paranaix :). Truth be told, this change wouldn't be needed if the "Base" class wasn't abstract. Also, for anyone who wants to take the inheritance needs to be declared public.

Comment: No you are wrong. 1) Your code will create a copy. 2) What you will expirience is called slicing, and you dont want that to happen. Simply remember: Never pass virtual objects by value!

Comment: Oooh this is great. I never new what virtual function could do but this is eye-opening.